# mysql query taking >4min with simple joins

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I am wondering if there is anything I could do to speed this query up.

The machine is an i7 with a 5900RPM HD. Is there anything I can do? collision sha1 does have an index and the rest of the joins are on primary keys

```
mysql> select count(*) from (
    -> select f.id, d1.name as dir, n1.name as name, c.sha1, size from file f
    -> join (select sha1 from collision group by sha1 having count(*)>1) msha on 1=1
    -> join collision c on c.id = f.id and c.sha1 = msha.sha1
    -> join NameList n1 on n1.id=f.name
    -> join directory d1 on d1.id=f.dir
    -> ) z;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    66469 |
+----------+
1 row in set (4 min 16.80 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from Collision;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   205713 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from (select sha1 from collision group by sha1 having count(*)>1) z;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    29915 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.98 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from (
    -> select f.id, d1.name as dir, n1.name as name, c.sha1, size from file f
    -> join (select sha1 from collision group by sha1 having count(*)>1) msha on 1=1
    -> join collision c on c.id = f.id and c.sha1 = msha.sha1
    -> join NameList n1 on n1.id=f.name
    -> join directory d1 on d1.id=f.dir
    -> ) z;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref           | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL       | NULL   | NULL             | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          |   NULL | Select tables optimized away    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | ALL    | NULL             | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          |  29915 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | c          | ALL    | PRIMARY          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 265854 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | f          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,dir,name | PRIMARY | 8       | filedb.c.id   |      1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | n1         | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY | 8       | filedb.f.name |      1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | d1         | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY | 8       | filedb.f.dir  |      1 |                                 |
|  3 | DERIVED     | collision  | ALL    | NULL             | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 265854 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+
7 rows in set (4 min 11.97 sec)
```

Comment: `from file f
   join (select sha1 from collision group by sha1 having count(*)>1) msha on 1=1` looks.... interesting. What are you trying to achieve with that join?

Comment: Try creating a compound index on collision table for `(id, sha1)`. If this does not help please post the explain after creating index.

Comment: Without understanding the query better, the best I can suggest is `select count(*) from (
  select f.id, d1.name as dir, n1.name as name, c.sha1, size from file f
  join collision c on c.id = f.id
  join (select sha1 from collision group by sha1 having count(*)>1) msha on c.sha1 = msha.sha1
  join NameList n1 on n1.id=f.name
  join directory d1 on d1.id=f.dir
) z;
` which at least avoids the `1=1` cartesian.

Comment: @Meherzad: I'm not sure what you mean or why that might help

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I think you might have figured it out by your second comment. I went a little further https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5530187

Comment: Create a compound index for `(id, sha1)` it will help in optimizing the ON clause for alias table c for which round about 250,000 rows are scanned.

Comment: @Meherzad: if `c` is innodb table, then a single column index `sha1` is enough, since primary key is clustered in innodb and is added as the right-most part automatically. PS: I assume that `id` is a PK PPS: a single col `sha1` index will also help to perform a nested query with `group by` better

Comment: @acidzombie24: it depends on how you store it. SHA1 is 160 bit long and can be presented as 40 chars hex string. If you follow that way `CHAR(40)` is what you need.

Comment: @zerkms: blah, there wasn't an index on sha1 on the collision table. wtf i could have sworn i did it earlier today when i was testing some queries. I did have two columns named sha1 maybe I dropped or added the index to the wrong one. Or maybe i modified the column and lost the index? anyways I changed the column to `varbinary(20) not null`

Comment: @acidzombie24: `binary(20)` is more suitable in this case

Comment: What is the purpose selecting so many fields when you just count rows at the top? To count rows you do not need to disturb so much data.

Comment: @newtover: The outer select is just so i can test my query without thousands of beeps from the mysql client console. But zerkms helped me out. All i needed to do was use binary(20) instead of tinyblob and put an index on it. I also tweaked the query as Joachim recommended so 1=1 isn't in it